# Access swift structure attribute using a variable

Tags: swift, swift-structs

I am new to swift and I am trying to find out, how to access the structure attribute through a variable. Being a JS developer, we are able to access the object key through a variable, so I am trying to find out if swift is also able to do the same?

```
//example in javascript
const someArray = [
   {key1: "value 1"},
]

const getValue1 = (key) => {
   return someArray[0][key]
}

//will return "value 1" 
getValue1(key1)
```

so likewise, for swift I am trying to access the attribute within a dictionary of structure items. Story has been initiated as a struct.

```
let stories = [
  Story(
            title: "Some Title",
            choice1: "Choice 1",
            choice2: "Choice 2",
        )
]

 func getChoiceText(choice: String) -> String {
   // get the choice string based on choice parameter -> "choice1" || "choice2"
   // eg something like this -> return stories[0][choice] 
 }

// so that I can get the corresponding choice text by calling the function 
getChoiceText(choice: "choice1")
```

thank you for your help in advance!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest equivalent in Swift is a generic function passing a key path

```
func getValue<T>(path: KeyPath<Story,T>) -> T {
    return stories[0][keyPath: path]
}
```

and call it

```
getValue(path: \.choice1)
```

But be aware that the code crashes if `stories` is empty.